# Bounds for $\log(1-x)$

Tags: inequality, taylor-expansion

I would like to show the following

> $$-x-x^2 \le \log(1-x) \le -x, \quad x \in [0,1/2].$$

I know that for $|x|<1$, we have $\log(1-x)=-\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\cdots\right)$. The inequality on the right follows because the difference is $\frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{3} + \cdots \ge 0$.

For the inequality on the left, the difference is $\frac{x^2}{2}-\left(\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4} + \cdots\right)$. How do I show this is nonnegative?

Comment: Hint: it's not true if you change $[0,0.5]$ to $[0,1)$.

Comment: All the intuition behind it is the Taylor expansion of the logarithm function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\log(1-x)+x+x^2\right) = 1+2x-\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{x(1-2x)}{1-x} $$
is a non-negative function on $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$, hence the LHS-inequality follows.

Comment: Nice. Haven't seem this before.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{array}\\
-\ln(1-x)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k}\\
&=x+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k}\\
&=x+x^2\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k-2}}{k}\\
&=x+x^2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k}}{k+2}\\
&\le x+x^2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k}}{2}\\
&\le x+\frac{x^2}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{k}\\
&= x+\frac{x^2}{2}\frac1{1-x}\\
&= x+\frac{x^2}{2(1-x)}\\
&\le x+x^2 \quad \text{if $0 \le x \le \frac12$}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Sorry for my delayed comment. May I ask how the $(-1)^{k+1}$ term disappears? Also, why do you start with a "-" in the formula? Could you please provide some information? The Taylor expansion I see in wiki is

$$\begin{align}\ln (z)  &= \frac{(z-1)^1}{1} - \frac{(z-1)^2}{2} + \frac{(z-1)^3}{3} - \frac{(z-1)^4}{4} + \cdots \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{(z-1)^k}{k}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Because I start with $-\ln(1-x)$. The $(-1)^n$ would be there if I started with $\ln(1+x)$.