# Does $X_n\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{law} 0$ imply$\mathbb{E}\left(\log |1-X_n| \right)\xrightarrow[n\to +\infty]{} 0$?

Tags: probability, weak-convergence

Let $(X_n)$ a sequence of random variables such that $X_n\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{law} 0$. I would like to show that $$\mathbb{E}\left(\log |1-X_n| \right)\xrightarrow[n\to +\infty]{} 0. $$
Intuitively, it seems natural. But since $x\mapsto \log |1-x|$ is not bounded on $\mathbb{R}$, it does not follow by definition of weak convergence.

Any hint/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: How about using https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171980/bounds-for-log1-x ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't follow. Say $(a_n)$ is a sequence of reals, and let $X_n$ be a random variable with $$p(X_n=0)=1-1/n,\quad P(X_n=a_n)=1/n.$$Then $X_n\to0$ in law regardless of the choice of $a_n$, but $$\mathbb{E}\left(\log |1-X_n| \right)=\log(|1-a_n|)/n$$need not tend to $0$.

For a maximally nasty example let $a_n=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your counterexample.

Comment: if $|X_n |< 1$ a.s. then we are good. But it is very restrictive. So I have another question, what (other) assumption could be needed to ensure the convergence ? Maybe if we have an exponential probability decay on the event $|X_n |< 1$ ?

Comment: No, $|X_n|<1$ a.s. is not enough. Same example as I gave - $|a_n|<1$ does not imply that $\log(|1-a_n|)/n\to0$.

Comment: yes of course you are right. Now, if we strengthen our hypothesis : $X_n\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{a.s.}0$, then a.s. $|X_n|<\frac{1}{2}$ (say) eventually, and the problem should be avoided ?

Comment: The example I gave may or may not tend to $0$ almost surely. Change it to $P(X_n=0)=1-1/n^2$, $P(X_n=a_n)=1/n^2$ and then $X_n\to0$ a.s., but $\log(|1-a_n|)/n^2$ still need not tend to $0$.